# Using CSS first-child to select first H2

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h2:first-child
{
background:yellow;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="car">
    <div>Something</div>
    <h2>I want to style this</h2>
    <p>bla bla</p>
    <h2>I don't want to style this</h2>
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm having trouble styling the first h2, "I want to style this" since I have a div right before that first h2 I can't select it, but if it weren't there it'll work. Without editing the html (and without using js of course) is there a way to select that first h2? Or is wrapping the h2's with another element like below the only way?

```
<div class="car">
    <div>Something</div>
<div>
        <h2>I want to style this</h2>
        <p>bla bla</p>
        <h2>I don't want to style this</h2>
        <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easier way than Sapph's method that is CSS2 using the adjacent selector:

`.car div + h2{}`

Comment: neat! didn't know that existed.

Comment: @Sapph thanks for your answer as well, I'll be using this method for now since some older versions of IE don't support CSS3. The first-of-type does have an advantage in that you don't need to know the element before it. I might start using it when more people use IE9.

Answer (score 12):

If you're willing to branch into [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo), the `first-of-type` selector is exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/m3yrR/1/

`first-of-type` will always select the first occurrence of an element at any level. So for your case, it would style the first `<h2>` at any level in the markup tree. You can of course use more specific selectors to limit where it gets selected. :)

Otherwise, yes, you'll have to do something like wrap it in another `<div>`, make sure it's the first element, and then do `div > h2:first-child`. Or just `h2:first-child`, if you want to be less specific.

Just make sure it's the first child (!!) of its parent, and be specific as you need to be with the parent-child hierarchy.